# How to make .next() take next word after last printed statement using Scanner class?

Tags: java, input

So for example, if I write this code:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("enter your favorite color");  
String age = scnr.next();  
System.out.println("now enter your birth month");  
String month = scnr.next();
```

And if I respond to "enter your favorite color" with "blue mostly", then it stores "blue" in age and "mostly" in month. I don't want that. I want it to only scan from everything after the last print statement. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good fit for the [`Console#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method.  This method prints a prompt, waits for user input, and then returns that input as a `String`.

### Code Sample

```
String color = System.console().readLine("enter your favorite color: ");
String month = System.console().readLine("now enter your birth month: " );
System.out.println("color: " + color);
System.out.println("month: " + month);
```

### Example Run

```
enter your favorite color: blue mostly
now enter your birth month: March
color: blue mostly
month: March
```

This is easier than parsing through the input manually using `Scanner` and similar classes.

If you want to keep only the first word entered by the user at the prompt, then you can use the [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method with a regular expression that matches whitespace to split it into an array of multiple `String` elements.  Then, you can pick the first one (element 0) and discard the rest.

### Code Sample

```
String color = System.console().readLine("enter your favorite color: ");
String month = System.console().readLine("now enter your birth month: " );
System.out.println("color: " + color.split("\\s+")[0]);
System.out.println("month: " + month.split("\\s+")[0]);
```

### Example Run

```
enter your favorite color: blue mostly
now enter your birth month: March
color: blue
month: March
```

For code that does a lot of repeated evaluation of the same regular expression, a helpful optimization can be to compile the regular expression to a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) object using [`Pattern#compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-).  (See the `Pattern` JavaDocs for more details on usage.)

Comment: I'm would want color to equal "blue" rather than "blue mostly" though. In my code, I tried fixing this by saying if (color.contains(" ")) { color = color.substring(0, color.indexOf(" ")); } but it gave me a String index out of range error when I gave it "blue" as my color. Is there a method that takes in just the first word of the line?

Comment: I edited the answer to add information about using the `String#split` method to get only the first word.  I hope this helps.